# Is there anyway for p.getInputStream() to be "live"?

Tags: java, process

Ok, what I'm trying to do is make a java GUI wrapper for another application. The issue i'm having is that I'm having problems making the output "live." At this moment, the application spits out all the application output at the end of the process being run. As the application being run is a map renderer tool for the game Minecraft, the output is basically a progress indicator of the current job, so it kinda needs to be live. The code I've been using at the moment is:

```
package net.rymate.overviewer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
*
* @author ryan
*/
public class Testmain {

    public Testmain(String commandline) {
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(commandline, "C:/exmaple/ C:/output").start();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new Testmain("C:/Documents and Settings/ryan/My Documents/overviewer-0.4.22-win32/overviewer.exe -v");
        new Testmain("C:/Documents and Settings/ryan/My Documents/overviewer-0.4.22-win32/overviewer.exe");
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT: seems the application only seems to be able to output anything but errors if its not run through cmd. So is there a way to run it through cmd via that implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the BufferedReader size is a simple but incorrect fix that will hang if the error stream (which you read second) produces a lot of output before you get around to reading it.  The correct way to do this is to create one thread for each stream that reads the data as soon as it's available.   It's up to you how you want to handle simultaneous output from both stdout and stderr.